# unable to create installer using Izpack

Tags: izpack

when i compile my install.xml file iam getting an error that resource not found. here is the error generated when i compile

C:\Program Files\IzPack\bin>compile D:\trail\simple\install.xml

```
.::  IzPack - Version 4.3.4 ::.

< compiler specifications version: 1.0 >

- Copyright (c) 2001-2008 Julien Ponge
- Visit http://izpack.org/ for the latest releases
- Released under the terms of the Apache Software License version 2.0.

-> Processing  : D:\trail\simple\install.xml
-> Output      : D:\trail\simple\install.jar
-> Base path   : .
-> Kind        : standard
-> Compression : default
-> Compr. level: -1
-> IzPack home : C:\Program Files\IzPack\bin\..

Adding resource: IzPack.uninstaller
Setting the installer information
Setting the GUI preferences
Adding langpack: eng
Adding resource: flag.eng
Adding langpack: fra
Adding resource: flag.fra
-> Fatal error :
   D:\trail\simple\install.xml:49: Resource not found: .\Readme.txt
com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerException: D:\trail\simple\install.xml:49: R
esource not found: .\Readme.txt
        at com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerConfig.parseError(Unknown Source)

        at com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerConfig.findProjectResource(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerConfig.addResources(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerConfig.executeCompiler(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerConfig.main(Unknown Source)
        at com.izforge.izpack.compiler.Compiler.main(Unknown Source)

(tip : use -? to get the commmand line parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing resource in your install.xml file.

```
D:\trail\simple\install.xml:49: Resource not found: .\Readme.txt
```

Provide this file or remove it from install.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

MY guess is that that your install.xml contains a InfoPanel reference like:

```
  <panels>
    <panel classname="InfoPanel" />
    ...
  </panels>
```

and a resourcedef like:

```
<resources>
  <res id="HTMLInfoPanel.info" src="Readme.txt" />
  ...
</resources>
```

which actually is referencing the missing "Readme.txt" file which will be shown in the info panel.

You should create this file or move it to the D:\trail\simple directory.